# How to concatenate two fields in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I am trying to combine two fields for e.g. `FullName = FirstName + LastName`

How can I accomplish in the following code?

```
IEnumerable<Item> Items = from item in _entities.Items
where Item.ID == Id 
orderby contractItem.Item.ItemName
select new Item
{
   Id = item.ID,
   ...
   CreatedBy = (from employee in _entities.Employees
                where employee.UserID == item.CreatedBy
                select new {
                             FirstLast = employee.FName + " " + employee.LName}).FirstOrDefault(), // <---- gives me an error
   ...
};
```

Comment: what error does it give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `CreatedBy` in `Item` is a type of `string` property and since in your query you are using `select new` it is creating an anonymous type. You can modify it like:

```
    (from employee in _entities.Employees
    where employee.UserID == contractItem.CreatedBy
    select employee.FName + " " + employee.LName).FirstOrDefault()
```

So your complete query would be like:

```
IEnumerable<Item> Items = from item in _entities.Items
where Item.ID == Id 
orderby contractItem.Item.ItemName
select new Item
{
   Id = item.ID,
   ...
   CreatedBy = (from employee in _entities.Employees
                where employee.UserID == item.CreatedBy
                select employee.FName + " " + employee.LName).FirstOrDefault(), 
};
```